# Odd ID behaviour from deployed API on Heroku

Tags: laravel, api, heroku, deployment, homestead

I have created an API and deployed using Heroku through GitHub.
I have tested my API using post-man and I have noticed a strange behaviour with the ids. They go from 1 then to 11, 21, 31 etc and so on - going up in 10s rather than by 1.
But when I test the homestead.test in post-man for my API it goes up by 1.

Does anyone know why my deployed url adds 10 to each id when posting data on post-man?
I've looked through my routes - which seem fine.
I've looked back through the controller/request and resource which again all look like how I have done previously. I have never used Heroku before so maybe I have done something that has made this behaviour happen - I just don't know what it is.

Any help from anyone would be much appreciated!

*Oh and I'm using Laravel with homestead, incase that is of any importance! *

Comment: I dont know about Heroku, but, assuming id is from  a database table, have you tested adding a row directly into the database? How does auto_increment_increment look like?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Are you talking about primary keys in your database? Which database are you using? Does it affect all of your models or just one of them?

Comment: When I add a new row of data into the data using artisan tinker it seems to auto increment like normal in mysql - it's only when i use the heroku deployed url that when i post it adds 10 to each id ? and i only have the one table in the data base so only one model - i've just found it to be very odd?